# convenience method in spray (soon to be akka-http) to create a Location header w/ host port & contextRoot ?

Tags: scala, rest, http-headers, akka, spray

When I create an object through POST in my Spray app I'd like to return a 201 status, together with a Location header that has the absolute URI of the newly created resource (including host port  & contextRoot of my app)

Here is an example code fragment from my application...

```
post {
  respondWithHeaders(Location( fullyQualifiedUri("/movies"))) {
    entity(as[MovieImpl]) { (movieToInsert: MovieImpl) => {
      addMovies(movieToInsert)
      complete("OK")
    }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I now have to write the method 'fullyQualifiedUri' to return 
a URI with host, port, etc.  It would be nice if Spray did that for me
automagically.

Side note:

I think that having the Location header include  the absolute URI of the newly
created resource makes it easier on my REST API's clients (although it does seem that there are a  variety of opinions on this.)

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.
 -chris

Comment: A comment on my side note, which is tangentially  related to my original question...  It seems  some of the differing opinions on relative vs. absolute URL's in Location header are actually due to the fact that there was a change in the HTTP spec.  According to Wikipedia, HTTP 1.1 allows relative URL's in the Location header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build the URI you'll need the Id of the newly created resource. Then you can use the `requestInstance` directive to get the incoming request URI and build the new resource URI from it. You also need to set the return code to `Created` to meet your requirements:

```
post {
  requestInstance { request =>
    val movieId = ???
    respondWithHeaders(Location( request.uri.withPath(request.uri.path / movieId))) {
      entity(as[MovieImpl]) { (movieToInsert: MovieImpl) => {
        addMovies(movieToInsert)
        complete(StatusCodes.Created)
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.     I should have thought of getting all that info from the request... anyway, thanks !